# How to check hadr state (suspend or resume) for a database?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, hadr

I can use below statements to suspend or resume HADR for a database.

```
ALTER DATABASE test SET HADR SUSPEND;
ALTER DATABASE test SET HADR RESUME;
```

How can I check a database is in HADR suspend or resume state using TSQL?

Answer (score 1):

Try it. Synchronization_state_desc and synchronization_health_desc columns.

```
 
SELECT  ag.name ag_name ,
        ar.replica_server_name ,
        adc.database_name ,
        hdrs.database_state_desc ,
        hdrs.synchronization_state_desc ,
        hdrs.synchronization_health_desc ,
        agl.dns_name ,
        agl.port
-- ,*
FROM    sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states hdrs
        LEFT JOIN sys.availability_groups ag ON hdrs.group_id =ag.group_id
        LEFT  JOIN sys.availability_replicas ar ON ag.group_id = ar.group_id
                                                   AND ar.replica_id = hdrs.replica_id
        LEFT  JOIN sys.availability_databases_cluster adc ON adc.group_id = ag.group_id
                                                             AND adc.group_database_id = hdrs.group_database_id
        LEFT  JOIN sys.availability_group_listeners agl ON agl.group_id = ag.group_id
ORDER BY ag.name , adc.database_name
```